# Updating SVG via Option selection

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am trying to get a text element within an SVG to update with an Option change.  After searching, I have been able to get to where I can see (in console) the option change within the initial load of the page, and when the option changes, but I have been unsuccessful with getting the number to change.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Dropdown Test</title>
      <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <select id="filter">
        <option value="GroupOne">Group One</option>
        <option value="secondTen">Group Two</option>
        <option value="thirdTen">Group Three</option>
      </select>

      <section id='svgCanvas'>
      </section>
      <script>
        var width = 100;
        var height = 100;

        var numberData = [
          {"Number":10,"Group":"GroupOne"},
          {"Number":13,"Group":"GroupTwo"},
          {"Number":6,"Group":"GroupThree"},
        ];

        var canvas = d3.select("#svgCanvas")
          .append('svg')
          .attr('height',height)
          .attr('width',width);

        function filterData(filterCriteria) {
            console.log(filterCriteria);

            var svgNumber = canvas.selectAll('text')
              .data(numberData);

            svgNumber.enter()
              .append('text')
              .filter(function(d){return d.Group == filterCriteria;})
              .text(function(d){return d.Number;})
              .attr('x',10)
              .attr('y',30)
              .attr('fill','#000000')
              .attr('id','numberText');

            svgNumber.exit().remove();
        };

        filterData('GroupOne');

        d3.select("#filter")
          .on('change', function() {
            var filter = d3.select(this).property('value');
            filterData(filter);
            console.log(filter);
          });
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `var filter = this.value`.

Comment: Do you mean in the ".on('change'...." function?  the problem doesn't seem to be here as when the filterData(filter) function is called, the console logs the correct value.

Comment: Sorry, when I read *"I have been unsuccessful with getting the number"* I thought your problem was getting the input value, not changing the text element. I just wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some changes:

1. Your options' values don't match your data array;
2. Apply the filter to the data itself;
3. Since this is D3 v4, `merge` the selections (from the second time on, your "enter" selection is always empty).

Here is the working code:

```js
var width = 100;
var height = 100;

var numberData = [{
    "Number": 10,
    "Group": "GroupOne"
}, {
    "Number": 13,
    "Group": "GroupTwo"
}, {
    "Number": 6,
    "Group": "GroupThree"
}, ];

var canvas = d3.select("#svgCanvas")
    .append('svg')
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('width', width);

function filterData(filterCriteria) {

    var svgNumber = canvas.selectAll('text')
        .data(numberData.filter(function(d) {
            return d.Group == filterCriteria;
        }));

    svgNumber.exit().remove();

    svgNumber.enter()
        .append('text')
        .attr('x', 10)
        .attr('y', 30)
        .attr('fill', '#000000')
        .attr('id', 'numberText')
        .merge(svgNumber)
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.Number;
        });

};

filterData('GroupOne');

d3.select("#filter")
    .on('change', function() {
        var filter = d3.select(this).property('value');
        //or just--> var filter = this.value;
        filterData(filter);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<select id="filter">
    <option value="GroupOne">Group One</option>
    <option value="GroupTwo">Group Two</option>
    <option value="GroupThree">Group Three</option>
</select>
<section id='svgCanvas'>
</section>
```