# How to make a drop-down filter in my visualisation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filter

I would love to implement a dropdown filter in my visualisation that allows me to filter by endorsed president. However, being very new to d3, I am really struggling. I have tried to implement it using code I have found elsewhere but to no avail.

```
            var dataPath = "data/p.csv";
            var dataPath2 = "data/e.csv";
            var field1=[];
            var field2=[];

            d3.csv(dataPath2,function(data){
                        data.map(function(d){
                            field1.push(d.year);
                            field2.push(d.publication);
                        })
                        //called after the AJAX is success
                        console.log("field1",field1);
                        console.log("field2",field2);
                        console.log("field1",field1[0]);

var myData = data;
var margin = 150,
    width = 1000 - margin,
    height = 2000 - margin;

/*
 * value accessor - returns the value to encode for a given data object.
 * scale - maps value to a visual display encoding, such as a pixel position.
 * map function - maps from data value to display value
 * axis - sets up axis
 */

// setup x
var yValue = function(d) { return d.publication;}, // data -> value
    yScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(field2).rangePoints([height, margin]); // value -> display
    yMap = function(d) { return yScale(yValue(d));}, // data -> display
        yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");

// setup y
var xValue = function(d) {  return d.year;}, // data -> value
      xExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
          return d.year;
          });
    xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain(xExtent).range([0,width-200]), // value -> display
    xMap = function(d) { return xScale(xValue(d));}, // data -> display
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom");
    //




//
// // setup fill color
var cValue = function(d) { return d.endorsed;},
    color = d3.scale.category10();
//
// // add the graph canvas to the body of the webpage
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin)
    .attr("height", height + margin)
  .append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(150)");

// add the tooltip area to the webpage
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);


  // x-axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis
        .ticks(12))
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", width-200)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Year");
//
//   // y-axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis
        .ticks(50))
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      // .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Publication");

  // draw dots
  svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 4)
      .attr("x", width - 10)
      .attr("y", 95)
      .attr("cx", xMap )
      .attr("cy", yMap)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(cValue(d));})

          // if (d.endorsed == "Clinton") { return "red"}
          // else {return "black"}; })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(1000)
               .style("opacity", .9);
          tooltip.html( d.endorsed
            )
               .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
               .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(1000)
               .style("opacity", 0);
      });

  // draw legend
  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  // draw legend colored rectangles
  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 10)
      .attr("y", 95)
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10)
      .style("fill", color);

  // draw legend text
  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 100)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d;})
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar requirement that I was able to solve [with help of others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42589878/updating-svg-via-option-selection), but you are going to need more than just d3.  Take a look at using JQuery to create dropdown options, and you can filter your data based on selections.